# Alternative to SQL Server Management Studio for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, database, sql

I am looking for an alternative to SQL Server Management Studio for Ubuntu.

I have worked with Pycharm Pro so far but I currently don't have the Pro version.

I looking for a noob friendly and with a modern interface that doesn't make me feel like I'm developing in the early 2000s...

Do you know any interesting alternatives?
Maybe Visual Studio Code or Azure studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Azure Data Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-ver15) from Microsoft should be an easy start for previous SSMS users.

[image: Azure Data Studio screenshot]